# Choosing item according to many constraints

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement, constraints

There are some locations that I visit each one according to some constraints. For example, I visit school `every day` at the `morning` and `noon` and I don't visit school on `weekends`.
Another one, I've been at the mall on `morning` time so I probably won't be there again today and also in the next few days (I don't work at the mall).

My question is if there is a good way to choose the right location from a data set looks like:

```
location         | types
MIT              | 'school'
western union    | 'accounting', 'finance'
Walmart          | 'store', 'home_goods_store'
```

And I know the constraints of each place, it depends on:

`the time of the day 
 is it a working day 
 how long I've been there
 the frequency of visiting
 have I been there today? this week? this month?`

and for each place, there is a different combination of values of constraints.

Right now I'm doing it with many dictionaries for each constraint but it looks pretty bad with so many `if statements`

Is there a better way to do it? Working with Python

**EDIT:**
My program needs to classify each activity according to all conditions.

```
freq_dic['low_freq'] =  ['airport','atm','bank','dentist','doctor','hospital','zoo','jewelry_store','spa']

freq_dic['high_freq'] = ['grocery_or_supermarket','gym','home_goods_store','primary_school','school',
                       'secondary_school','shopping_mall','store','supermarket','university']

time_dic['morning'] = ['airport', 'atm','bakery','bank','beauty_salon','bicycle_store','book_store','cafe',
                   'clothing_store','dentist','doctor','drugstore','gym','hair_care','home_goods_store',
                  'hospital','jewelry_store','library','local_government_office','pharmacy','primary_school',
                  'school','secondary_school','shopping_mall','spa','store','supermarket','university','zoo']

time_dic['noon'] = ['atm','bakery','bank','beauty_salon','bicycle_store','book_store','cafe','clothing_store',
               'convenience_store','dentist','department_store','doctor','drugstore','grocery_or_supermarket',
                'gym','hair_care','home_goods_store','hospital','jewelry_store','library','local_government_office',
               'primary_school','restaurant','school','secondary_school','shopping_mall','spa','store',
                'supermarket','university']

time_dic['evening'] = ['bakery','bar','bicycle_store','cafe','convenience_store','department_store','drugstore',
                   'grocery_or_supermarket','gym','home_goods_store','hospital','jewelry_store','movie_theater',
                  'night_club','restaurant','shopping_mall','store','supermarket']

 visited_today_dic = {}
   ...
```

and for each row in the data set I isolated the time and frequency and send it to this function:

```
def find_list(c_time, freq):

if  7 <= c_time <= 12:
    if freq <= 6:
        return list(set(time_dic['morning']).intersection(freq_dic['low_freq']))
    elif freq <= 9:
        return list(set(time_dic['morning']).intersection(freq_dic['med_freq']))
    else:
        return list(set(time_dic['morning']).intersection(freq_dic['high_freq']))
elif 12 < c_time <= 17:
    if freq <= 6:
        return list(set(time_dic['noon']).intersection(freq_dic['low_freq']))
    elif freq <= 9:
        return list(set(time_dic['noon']).intersection(freq_dic['med_freq']))
    else:
        return list(set(time_dic['noon']).intersection(freq_dic['high_freq']))
else:
    if freq <= 6:
        return list(set(time_dic['evening']).intersection(freq_dic['low_freq']))
    elif freq <= 9:
        return list(set(time_dic['evening']).intersection(freq_dic['med_freq']))
    else:
        return list(set(time_dic['evening']).intersection(freq_dic['high_freq']))
```

and now for every activity, I choose the right dictionary from each category(time, frequency, visiting, duration...) and choose only the location with types fit to all values from dictionary i.e. if the activity is with everyday frequency and the time is morning and I have not been there today so I will look at all values from `freq_dic['high_freq']`, and from `time_dic['morning']` and choose only the common places

TIA

Comment: _Right now I'm doing it with many dictionaries for each constraint but it looks pretty bad with so many if statements_ Where is the code? If your program works, this question probably belongs on Code Review, not Stack Overflow. It isn't even clear to me what your program is meant to do.

Comment: Just edited and added some code

Comment: You've added dict definitions, not any logic on what you have attempted so far.

Comment: Added. to logic is just finding common values between all list which mean it satisfies all conditions